# Как выровнять все блоки при float:left?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы каждый блок строго шел за следующим и если один из них выше другого - чтобы не терялась структура, как сейчас в коде ниже:

```css
.style_block {
  width: 23%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="style_block">
  Блок
</div>
<div class="style_block">
  Блок2 Блок2 Блок2 Блок2 Блок2 Блок2 Блок2 Блок2 Блок2 Блок2 Блок2 
</div>
<div class="style_block">
  Блок
</div>
<div class="style_block">
  Блок
</div>
<div class="style_block">
  Блок
</div>
<div class="style_block">
  Блок
</div>
<div class="style_block">
  Блок
</div>
<div class="style_block">
  Блок
</div>
<div class="style_block">
  Блок
</div>
```

Comment: если очень сильно нужно через флоат, то на сцену нужно будет пригласить js))) а так, флекс бокс, думю идеально подойдет)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение с помощью Flexbox Вам подходит?

Или нужно именно на Float?

```css
section {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.style_block {
    width: 23%;
    /* float: left; */
    background-color: #eee;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="style_block">
        Блок
    </div>
    <div class="style_block">
        Блок2 Блок2 Блок2 Блок2 Блок2 Блок2 Блок2 Блок2 Блок2 Блок2 Блок2
    </div>
    <div class="style_block">
        Блок
    </div>
    <div class="style_block">
        Блок
    </div>
    <div class="style_block">
        Блок
    </div>
    <div class="style_block">
        Блок
    </div>
    <div class="style_block">
        Блок
    </div>
    <div class="style_block">
        Блок
    </div>
    <div class="style_block">
        Блок
    </div>
</section>
```